# Need to create a Binary Search Tree with a custom comparator, can't seem to get it to work

Tags: java, binary-tree, treeset

I'm trying to create a Binary Search Tree using a TreeSet. I'm aware that by definition, a set does not contain any duplicate entries. However, I am sure that if I create my own comparator, I can allow the TreeSet to take in duplicate entries. I've done so:

```
public class A3BSTree <E> implements Tree <E> {

    private TreeSet<E> tree;
    private LinkedList<E> arr1;
    private MyComparator comp;

    public A3BSTree(){
        tree = new TreeSet<>(comp);
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private class MyComparator implements Comparator<E> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public int compare(E e1, E e2) {
            if (((A3BSTree<E>.MyComparator) e1).compareTo(e2) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (e1.equals(e2)) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public int compareTo(E e) {
            return this.compareTo(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I don't want the answer, I just need an explanation on why the TreeSet still won't take in duplicates. I just need to be steered in the right direction. Could the problem be that I cannot create a Comparator with generics?

Comment: Why are you casting element to Comparator class?

Comment: Define what you mean duplicates? From the comparator code above if `e1` and `e2` are equals then they will be treated as duplicates by `TreeSet`.

Comment: VDanyliuk: The compiler wanted me to.

Comment: tsolakp: If the elements are numbers (int, long, etc.) then equal numbers. If strings, then equal strings. But I'm required to use generics, so there seems to be ambiguity in what are equal, or duplicate, values.

Answer (score 1):

**java.util.TreeSet add() method**

*java.util.TreeSet* class uses the add method to add elements into the Set. This method does not allow duplicates. It detects duplicates using the *equals()* method as mentioned in [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)).

> public boolean add(E e)
>   Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

**Current comparator implementation**

As per your *Comparator* implementation, you expect the equals method to identify duplicates (probably you have overridden it?).

```
} else if (e1.equals(e2)) {
    return 0;
}
```

If that is the case, I believe the behavior of TreeSet is correct in rejecting the duplicates based on the *equals()* method.

On the other hand, may be it is better to use Comparable approach rather than Comparator here as that allows objects to be comparable with its own instances (difference is [explained here](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html)).